# How to dynamically assign a type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an array of objects

```
type ItemTypes = {
    name: string;
    age: in;
}

let items: ItemTypes[] = [
    {name: "Alex", age: 28},
    {name: "Dave", age: 41}
]
```

But let's say that, initially the values of **items** are undefined/empty. Typescript throws an error that **Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ItemTypes[]**

I have tried the following

```
let items: ItemTypes[] | undefined = [
    {name: "Alex", age: 28},
    {name: "Dave", age: 41}
]
```

But since I am looping the **items** to generate the HTML, typescript shows the error - Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike'.

How can I address this.

Comment: If I understand correctly you can use `(items as ItemTypes[])` once you are sure they are not undefined.

Comment: Then why are assigning `undefined` try to assign `[ ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make it work you need to narrow `items` variable:

```js
type ItemTypes = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

declare let items: ItemTypes[] | undefined

// expected error
items.map(e => 2)

// ok
if (items) {
  items.map(e => 2)
}
```

See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) . TS does not allow you to call Array methods on a value which might be `undefined` because it may lead to runtime errors, hence you need to assure typescript that this value is not `undefined`

Comment: Nit: when using the `const` keyword, a value can never be reassigned to `items`, so if it starts out as an array, it'll always be an array, but if it starts out `undefined` it'll forever be `undefined`.

Comment: Do you really need `declare` here? I thought it was only needed to help with external JS libraries that do not have type definitions.

Comment: @Kokodoko I use `declare` when I am interested only in fixing type issues. In this case, I am not interested in runtime value, this is why I was using `declare`. I should have to add that `declare` should not be used in `prod` in this particulare case